# Graphicspath with several paths not working when only defined in the subfile

Tags: includegraphics, subfiles

I have a main document which calls several modules and also uses images from upper folders, this is the structure of the folders:

- Icons
- Common

  - Covers
- Test

  - All

    - main.tex
  - Module

    - subfile.tex
    - Figures

      - figure.png

This is the code of the main:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm,footskip=1.7cm]{geometry} %proper formatting for a4pages
\usepackage{graphicx} %allows the inclusion of graphics and resizing rotating etc.
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %allows use of complex headers and footers
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true,hypertexnames=true,hyperfootnotes=false,pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfiles} % allows inclusion of chapter files which can also be compiled stand-alone
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} 
\usepackage{watermark}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\graphicspath{{../../Common/Covers/}} 


\begin{document}


\leftwatermark{\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{bg-page-left.pdf}} %these are in folder covers
\rightwatermark{\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{bg-page-right.pdf}}

% table of contents has own roman numeral numbering
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark} % put the chapter name in the right hand corner
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\color{white}{\thepage}}
\fancyfootoffset[LE,RO]{2.5cm}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\raisebox{-0.3cm}{Test}}
\fancyfootoffset[LO,RE]{0cm}

\tableofcontents                    % table of contents

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagebreak

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:Intro}

A small introduction 

\pagebreak

\subfile{../Module/Subfile.tex} 


\end{document}
```

And this is the code of the subfile:

```
\documentclass[../All/main.tex]{subfiles}


\graphicspath{{\subfix{../../Icons/}}                %don't touch
             {\subfix{../Module/Figures/}}}    %change the name of the folder accordingly

\begin{document}

\section{Name of the Section}


\subsection{Name of the Subsection}


Use the icon \includegraphics[width=13px,height=9px]{/toolboxes/printpreview/pagenext.png} to jump to next page. %this figure is in the Icons folder

This figure is in the Figures folder inside the module

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle= 0, width=0.8\textwidth]{figure.png}
    \caption{Just a cat picture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

It used to work with previous versions, but since I updated it does not work anymore. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Just one more clarification, I know that if I define the paths in the main and the subfile it works, but I would like to only define the figures path in the subfile, like before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between `subfiles v1.x` and `subflies v2.x`, there was a major change in the default behaviour. Load `subfiles` with the option `v1` to get the old behaviour back.

```
\usepackage[v1]{subfiles}
```

In version `v1.x`, the `\subfile` command would processes also the preamble of the subfile as well as all the stuff after `\end{document}`, which for most users comes unexpected and has some peculiarities.

In version `v2.x`, the `\subfile` command includes only the stuff between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. In your use case, the `\graphicspath` command in the preamble of the subfile will be ignored when loading the file with `\subfile`, and the figure will not be found. The package option `v1` restores the old behaviour. For more information, see the documentation of the package.